# List index out of range while writing image files into tfrecords

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am creating tfrecords files for images and i am getting error as

```
100%|########################################################################################################################################| 116/116 [02:40<00:00,  1.39s/it]
 69%|##############################################################################################1                                          | 79/115 [01:58<00:53,  1.50s/it]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "write_tfrecords_for_inference.py", line 54, in <module>
    video_id = int(seq[0].split('_')[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code for above is here

```
if not os.path.isdir(tfrecord_folder):
    os.makedirs(tfrecord_folder)

data_point_names = dpc.get_data_point_names(args.data_dir, in_sequences=True,
    longest_seq=args.longest_seq)

splits = [[] for _ in range(args.n_divides)]
for i in range(len(data_point_names)):
    splits[i%args.n_divides].append(data_point_names[i])

for i in range(len(splits)):
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(
        os.path.join(tfrecord_folder, 
        "cameras_%d.tfrecords" % i )) as writer:    
        
        for seq in tqdm(splits[i]):
            camera_features = list()
            feature_map_features = list()
            gazemap_features = list()
            gaze_ps_features = list()
            video_id = int(seq[0].split('_')[0])
            predicted_time_point_features = list()
            weight_features = list()
            
            for j in range(len(seq) - args.n_future_steps):
                # write camera images
                camera = cv2.imread(os.path.join(camera_folder,seq[j]+'.jpg'))              
                camera = cv2.resize(
                  camera, 
                  tuple(args.image_size[::-1]),
                  interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR
                )
                camera = camera[:,:,::-1]   # flip bgr

                camera_features.append(_bytes_feature(camera.tostring()))
                
                # write frame names
                time_point = int(seq[j+args.n_future_steps].split('_')[1])
                predicted_time_point_features.append(_int64_feature(time_point))
            
            feature_lists = {'cameras': tf.train.FeatureList(feature=camera_features),
                             'gaze_ps': tf.train.FeatureList(feature=gaze_ps_features),
                             'predicted_time_points': \
                               tf.train.FeatureList(feature=predicted_time_point_features),
                             'weights': tf.train.FeatureList(feature=weight_features)}
            features = {'video_id': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[video_id]))}
            
            example = tf.train.SequenceExample(
                context=tf.train.Features(feature=features),
                feature_lists=tf.train.FeatureLists(feature_list=feature_lists))
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

This code is working for small dataset and creating the tfrecord files but while working with large dataset it throws the above error. Maybe it is memory issue of numpy , but i am unable to get to the exact cause. Please let me know where i need to improve the code.

I am using numpy1.18.7 and tensorflow gpu1.5 .

Comment: I am guessing that the split("_") result is empty, so getting `[0]` raises an exception

Comment: @Blake is probably right, except the problem is that `seq` is an empty list. `str.split` would return at minimum a list of length 1.  The `IndexError` is coming from `seq[0]`

Comment: All the files in data folders are ' 1737_00333.jpg ' in this format so it must return some number after split. I am also checking if is there any exception in file names.

Comment: Printing `seq` would probably show the problem.

Comment: for all the runs it is showing seq as ``` ['1945_00000', '1945_00333', '1945_00666', '1945_01000', '1945_01333', '1945_01666', '1945_02000', '1945_02333', '1945_02666', '1945_03000', '1945_03333', '1945_03666', '1945_0
4000', '1945_04333', '1945_04666', '1945_05000', '1945_05333', '1945_05666', '1945_06000', '1945_06333', '1945_06666', '1945_07000', '1945_07333', '1945_07666', '1945_08000', '
1945_08333', '1945_08666', '1945_09000', '1945_09333', '1945_11333'] ```                         but when it terminates for that run it returns seq as ``` [] ```

Comment: len(seq) is 116